# c# RequestStream changes equal to comma

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, stream, httpwebrequest

I have a program where I am using POST to send an XML message to an endpoint. It is properly formed in the output both before and after being converted to a byte array, but once it is received by the endpoint, the first = is turned into a , causing parsing issues.

ie `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` becomes `<?xml version', '"1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`, but only for outermost tag.

Can anyone clarify why this happens, and how to prevent it? None of my tweaks seem to be helping.

Thanks!

(Note: I tried using the XML Serialization class, but this has a high volume output, sometimes as high as 9-12 messages every 3 seconds, and it was causing memory management problems since it was spawning csc.exe for each message.)

Here is my code:

```
        DateTimeOffset dateOffset = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now,
                        TimeZoneInfo.Local.GetUtcOffset(DateTime.Now));


        string xmlToSend = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"
            + "<message type=\"" + "VEHICLE" + "\" time=\"" + dateOffset.ToString("o") + "\" "
            + "xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">"
            + "<tag1>" + "TESTER" + "</tag1>"
            + "<tag2>" + "TESTER" + "</tag2>"
            + "<tag3>" + "TESTER" + "</tag3>"
            + "<tag4>" + "TESTER" + "</tag4>"
            + "<confidence>" + "TESTER" + "</confidence>"
            + "</message>";

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(xmlToSend);

        Console.WriteLine("doc to string: " + doc.OuterXml);

        byte[] bytes;
        bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(doc.OuterXml);
        Console.WriteLine("bytes to string: " + Encoding.Default.GetString(bytes));


            Uri temp = new Uri("http://localhost:1337/");


            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((WaitCallback)delegate(Object myObj)
            {
                try
                {

                    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(temp);

                    //Set HttpWebRequest properties

                    request.Method = "POST";
                    request.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding='utf-8'";
                    request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
                    request.Timeout = 5000;

                    Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
                    requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);


                    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                    Console.WriteLine("Endpoint: " + temp.AbsoluteUri + "; Status code: " + response.StatusCode);



                    response.Close();
                    requestStream.Close();
                    request = null;

                }


                catch (Exception e)
                {
                        Console.WriteLine("ERROR: Posting to the endpoint didn't work - " + e.Message + "(" + temp.AbsoluteUri + ")");

                }

            });
```

And here is the console output:

```
doc to string: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><message type="VEHICLE" tim
e="2013-05-17T15:44:38.3593750-07:00" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchem
a-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><tag1>TESTER</tag1><tag
2>TESTER</tag2><tag3>TESTER</tag3><tag4>TESTER</tag4><confidence>TESTER</confide
nce></message>
bytes to string: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><message type="VEHICLE" t
ime="2013-05-17T15:44:38.3593750-07:00" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSch
ema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><tag1>TESTER</tag1><t
ag2>TESTER</tag2><tag3>TESTER</tag3><tag4>TESTER</tag4><confidence>TESTER</confi
dence></message>
Endpoint: http://localhost:1337/; Status code: OK
```

and my local server output:

```
[('<?xml version', '"1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><message type="VEHICLE" time="2013-0
5-17T15:44:38.3593750-07:00" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instanc
e" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><tag1>TESTER</tag1><tag2>TESTER<
/tag2><tag3>TESTER</tag3><tag4>TESTER</tag4><confidence>TESTER</confidence></mes
sage>')]
```

Comment: Could do with seeing your server code.  You're server is showing you a structure with two strings.  The first contains `<?xml version`, whilst the second contains the rest of your XML.  The XML says it is UTF-8, but the code uses `System.Text.Encoding.ASCII` to encode the data rather than `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8`.  I'm not sure if this is the cause of the problem, but it won't help.

Answer (score 0):

This is an encoding issue, your endpoint making the best effort at understanding something which contains errors

```
    bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(doc.OuterXml);
    Console.WriteLine("bytes to string: " + Encoding.Default.GetString(bytes));
```

You create your bytes in ASCII encoding, then use default encoding, i.e. ANSI, to do your output. And then, in the XML and in the request content type, you tell the server that this would be UTF-8:

```
    request.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding='utf-8'";
```

You should always use UTF-8 if possible. So get rid of ASCII and ANSI (default), encode with UTF-8, and your problem will probably go away.

Comment: I tried changing the encoding to UTF8 and the ContentType to "application/xml" but I'm still getting the same output in both windows. But that was still a good change to make to be consistent.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if your response content type is defaulting to the wrong value and confusing the client - setting it may help:

```
response.ContentType = "application/xml";
```

Comment: I tried that, and it didn't change anything on the output end. It was still a good change to make though.